bound on product of bezout coefficients
I am looking to prove that for any two positive integers $2 \leqslant a < b$ and $a$ does not divide $b$, let $(x_0,y_0)$ be the smallest pair of bezout coefficients $ax_0+by_0=d=gcd(a,b)$ we should have
$$ |x_0y_0| < \left\lfloor\sqrt{ab}\right\rfloor^2$$
This result is trivial for the cases where $d > 1$ and is a direct consequence of Extended Euclidean Algorithm. It follows from the fact that $|x_0| < \frac{b}{d}$ and $|y_0| < \frac{a}{d}$.
Can anyone help with the extension to the case where $d=1$ ?

In the general case where $d = 1$ you still get $|x_0| \leqslant b - 1$ and $|y_0| \leqslant a - 1$.
Therefore, as $2 \sqrt{ab} \leqslant a + b$ by the AM-GM inequality, you get :
$$
|x_0 y_0| \leqslant ab - (a + b) + 1 \leqslant ab - 2\sqrt{ab} + 1 = (\sqrt{ab} - 1)^2 < \lfloor \sqrt{ab} \rfloor^2
$$

Thanks @JohnOmielan for the correction, I'm editing it.

Thanks Jean; it is so simple
